# What literary device is used in "I am in the mood for dying"?

Tags: literature

> “She was my last, Jason, and I am saying it because it is true. Don’t look for me to keep you alive again when we set foot in Birchtown. *Because I am in the mood for dying*”

Specifically the phrase in italics. For context, the speaker had lost her daughter.

Comment: what book/movie/etc is this from? Can you provide more of the passage? more context is necessary here.

Comment: Are you asking us to identify the literary device? What does this have to do with learning English? You might be better off asking this question in writing.SE.

Answer (score 2):

The words highlighted aren't really an idiom. Given the limited context, it seems literal - the speaker has a *deathwish*.

People want to die (or say they do) for numerous reasons. In this case, it seems that the loss of their daughter has taken away their reason to live, or their joy in life has gone. This doesn't imply they are intending suicide - it can just mean that, if faced with death, they wouldn't have the will to fight it.

I wouldn't say that these words alone are using a 'literary device', although they may be helping set up the character in a way that functions as one - for example, casting the speaker as a '*tragic hero*' if they have suffered a loss.

Comment: I wonder if the author had heard a certain song by the Nolans, an Irish group?